# Room Database with UNIQUE constraint on multiple columns

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to build a Room database which will apply a unique constraint to a combination of three columns, so a conflict will only emerge if all three columns of the incoming record are matched by all three of an existing record.

My current attempt (below) gives a conflict if any of the three columns conflicts, and I'm finding it difficult to discover a solution to this.

Database class:

```java
@Database(entities = {OutputPreset.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class PresetDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    static final String FILENAME = "presets.db";
    public abstract PresetDao getDao();
}
```

Simplified OutputPreset class:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "Presets", indices = { @Index(value = {"Address", "Port", "Protocol"}, unique = true) } )
public class OutputPreset {
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Protocol")
    public final String protocol;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Address")
    public final String address;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Port")
    public final int port;

    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, the `@Index(value = {"Address", "Port", "Protocol"}, unique = true)` statement is just applying the uniqueness constraint to each column individually, rather than grouping them.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Turns out the issue was that the Primary Key wasn't auto-generating for each record, so they were just overwriting each other whenever I inserted something. Fixed by setting the ID's annotation to `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

Comment: _...is just applying the uniqueness constraint to each column individually, rather than grouping them_ -- Not according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room), which indicates that your declaration is creating a composite index.  It should work as you expect, allowing duplicates for each individual column, but requiring the three, taken together, to be unique.  You can see the SQL statement used to create the index by [enabling export of your DB schema](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema).

Comment: @BobSnyder You're very much correct! It turns out the problem was that my primary key column wasn't autogenerating, so I updated the annotation to `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` and now it's working like a charm!. So that was causing each entry I inserted to just overwrite the previous one.